# How to find all files containing a specific string recursively on a BusyBox 1.4.2?

Tags: shell, grep, recursive, busybox

How to find all files containing a specific string within directory and all subdirectories on a BusyBox v1.4.2? I need to find string "AA:CC:DD:00:EE:55" or "AACCDD00EE55"

```
BusyBox v1.4.2 (2012-06-01 11:17:34 CST) Built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

Built-in commands:
-------------------
        . : [ [[ bg break cd chdir continue echo eval exec exit export
        false fg getopts hash help jobs kill local pwd read readonly
        return set shift source test times trap true type ulimit umask
        unset wait


# busybox --help
BusyBox v1.4.2 (2012-06-01 11:17:34 CST) multi-call binary

Usage: busybox [function] [arguments]...
   or: [function] [arguments]...

Currently defined functions:
        [, [[, adduser, ash, awk, cat, chmod, chroot, cp, cut,
        date, dd, deluser, dmesg, echo, false, free, getopt, grep,
        halt, hexdump, hostname, htxsnmptelnet, ifconfig, init,
        insmod, kill, killall, ln, login, ls, lsmod, mkdir, mknod,
        mount, mv, netstat, passwd, ping, ping6, poweroff, ps,
        pwd, reboot, renice, rm, rmmod, route, sh, sleep, tar,
        test, tftp, top, umount, wget
```

Comment: `busybox grep --help` will show you `grep`'s options.

Answer (score 3):

`grep` has a recursive flag `-r`, and allows specifying multiple search patters with `-e` flag. Also, from the format you seem to be looking for a mac address, so that could be upper or lower case.

Knowing that you could do

`grep -ir -e "AA:CC:DD:00:EE:55"  -e "AACCDD00EE55" /directory`

Notice that you have to specify `sudo` in case you don't have read permissions for files/folders, such as `/etc` folder.

For instance,

```
xieerqi:$ grep -iR "string" /etc/cups                                                                              
grep: /etc/cups/subscriptions.conf: Permission denied
grep: /etc/cups/classes.conf: Permission denied
grep: /etc/cups/printers.conf.O: Permission denied
grep: /etc/cups/subscriptions.conf.O: Permission denied
grep: /etc/cups/ssl: Permission denied
grep: /etc/cups/printers.conf: Permission denied
```

That happens because permissions of all items in `/etc/cups` and the directory itself have read-write permissions only for root user, and read permissions for `lp` group. For other users - no read permissions. For instance,

```
-rw-r----- 1 root lp     92 11月  6 09:15 subscriptions.conf
```

That's why you need sudo access.

Additionally, `grep` may complain about not being able to read an entry, so you may need to specify `2> /dev/null` redirection

For instance, I get the following error because `/etc/blkid.tab` is a symlink, not an actual file.

```
xieerqi:$ sudo grep -iR "b4:82:fe:d3:85:56" /etc                                                                  
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
grep: /etc/blkid.tab: No such file or directory
```

To make the error disappear from the output, I'd do `sudo grep -iR "b4:82:fe:d3:85:56" 2> /dev/null`, which redirects error stream to `/dev/null` device, basically black-hole for any output

Comment: busybox's version of grep doesn't support `-R`.  It does support `-r`.

Comment: On some directories grep complains `grep: Permission denied`. Please clarify about `2> /dev/null` redirection, where this need be specified? Also, the target strings need be inside quotation marks?

Comment: As i said permission denied means you need sudo to read those directories. So append sudo before grep command. 2> /dev/null sends errors to null device ,ie they wont be displayed. Example, compare  ls thisfiledoesnt exist and ls thisfie doesn't exist >/dev/null

Comment: It's hard to edit my answer on mobile. Ill edit it in 15 mins when i get to my laptop

Comment: Edited answer, please review

Comment: @Serg A few notes: Busybox 1.4.2 have no sudo command, so I can no use it. On two directories, `/var` and `/dev`, grep hangs up, process keeps running without seems to do anything, just hang without errors on new line, no shebang, so it requires restart CLI and new session. The `/var` directory contains sub-dirs with drwxr-xr-x permission, except one which is prw-r--r--; the `/dev` contains sub-dirs with crw-rw----, brw-rw----, crw-r--r-- permissions.